# Nested fetch join with JPQL and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am writing a JPQL query (with Hibernate as my JPA provider) to fetch an entity `Company` and several of its associations. This works fine with my "simple" ManyToMany associations, like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Company.profile.view.byId",
                query = "SELECT c " +
                        "FROM Company AS c " +
                        "INNER JOIN FETCH c.city AS city " + <-- @ManyToOne
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.acknowledgements " + <-- @ManyToMany
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.industries " + <-- @ManyToMany
                        "WHERE c.id = :companyId"
        )
})
public class Company { ... }
```

Hibernate creates a single query to fetch the above, which is good. However, my `Company` entity also has a many-to-many association with data stored in the intermediate table, hence why this is mapped as `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` associations between three entities.

> Company <-- CompanyService --> Service

These are the three entities that I have in my code. So a `Company` instance has a collection of `CompanyService` entities, which each has a relation to a `Service` instance. I hope that makes sense - otherwise please check the source code at the end of the question.

Now I would like to fetch the services for a given company by modifying the above query. I read in advance that JPA doesn't allow nested fetch joins or even aliases for joins, but that some JPA providers do support it, and so I tried my luck with Hibernate. I tried to modify the query as such:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Company.profile.view.byId",
                query = "SELECT c " +
                        "FROM Company AS c " +
                        "INNER JOIN FETCH c.city AS city " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.acknowledgements " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.industries " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.companyServices AS companyService " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH companyService.service AS service " +
                        "WHERE c.id = :companyId"
        )
})
public class Company { ... }
```

Now, instead of creating a single query, Hibernate creates the following queries:

```
#1
select ...
from company company0_
inner join City city1_ on company0_.postal_code = city1_.postal_code
[...]
left outer join company_service companyser6_ on company0_.id = companyser6_.company_id
left outer join service service7_ on companyser6_.service_id = service7_.id
where company0_.id = ?

#2
select ...
from company company0_
inner join City city1_ on company0_.postal_code = city1_.postal_code
where company0_.id = ?

#3
select service0_.id as id1_14_0_, service0_.default_description as default_2_14_0_, service0_.name as name3_14_0_
from service service0_
where service0_.id = ?

#4
select service0_.id as id1_14_0_, service0_.default_description as default_2_14_0_, service0_.name as name3_14_0_
from service service0_
where service0_.id = ?
```

**Query #1**
I left out the irrelevant joins as these are OK. It appears to select all of the data that I need, including the services and the intermediate entity data (`CompanyService`).

**Query #2**
This query simply fetches the company from the database and its `City`. The city association is eagerly fetched, but the query is still generated even if I change it to lazy fetching. So honestly I don't know what this query is for.

**Query #3 + Query #4**
These queries are looking up `Service` instances based on ID, presumably based on service IDs fetched in Query #1. I don't see the need for this query, because this data was already fetched in Query #1 (just as the data from Query #2 was already fetched in Query #1). Also, this approach obviously does not scale well if a company has many services.

The strange thing is that it seems like query #1 does what I want, or at least it fetches the data that I need. I just don't know why Hibernate creates query #2, #3 and #4. So I have the following questions:

- Why does Hibernate create query #2, #3 and #4? And can I avoid it?
- Does Hibernate support nested association fetching even though JPA doesn't? If so, how would I go about it in my case?
- Is this behavior normal, or is it because what I am trying to do is just not supported, and therefore I get weird results? This would seem odd, because query #1 looks perfectly fine

Any pointers of mistakes or alternative solutions to accomplish what I want would be much appreciated. Below is my code (getters and setters excluded). Thanks a lot in advance!

**Company entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Company.profile.view.byId",
                query = "SELECT c " +
                        "FROM Company AS c " +
                        "INNER JOIN FETCH c.city AS city " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.acknowledgements " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.industries " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.companyServices AS companyService " +
                        "LEFT JOIN FETCH companyService.service AS service " +
                        "WHERE c.id = :companyId"
        )
})
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    // ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = City.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postal_code")
    private City city;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "company_acknowledgement", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "acknowledgement_id"))
    private Set<Acknowledgement> acknowledgements;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "company_industry", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "industry_id"))
    private Set<Industry> industries;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
    private Set<CompanyService> companyServices;
}
```

**CompanyService entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_service")
@IdClass(CompanyServicePK.class)
public class CompanyService implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Company.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Service.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id")
    private Service service;

    @Column
    private String description;
}
```

**Service entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service")
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "default_description", nullable = false)
    private String defaultDescription;
}
```

**Fetching data**

```
public Company fetchTestCompany() {
    TypedQuery<Company> query = this.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Company.profile.view.byId", Company.class);
    query.setParameter("companyId", 123);

    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: I wonder where you read that JPA does not allow nested FETCH JOIN statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems like I figured it out. By setting the fetch type to `FetchType.LAZY` in `CompanyService`, Hibernate stopped generating all of the redundant queries that were basically fetching the same data again. Here is the new version of the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_service")
@IdClass(CompanyServicePK.class)
public class CompanyService implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Company.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Service.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id")
    private Service service;

    @Column
    private String description;
}
```

The JPQL query remains the same.

However, in my particular case with the number of associations my `Company` entity has, I was getting a lot of duplicated data back, and so it was more efficient to let Hibernate execute an additional query. I accomplished this by removing the two join fetches from my JPQL query and changing my query code to the below.

```
@Transactional
public Company fetchTestCompany() {
    TypedQuery<Company> query = this.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Company.profile.view.byId", Company.class);
    query.setParameter("companyId", 123);

    try {
        Company company = query.getSingleResult();
        Hibernate.initialize(company.getCompanyServices());

        return company;
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

By initializing the `companyServices` association, Hibernate executes another query to fetch the services. In my particular use case, this is better than fetching a ton of redundant data with one query.

I hope this helps someone. If anyone has any better solutions/improvements, then I would of course be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote, I would say that nested fetching isn't supported. This is my understanding of your results:

- **Query #1** is ok, and joins everything that it needs, this is good
- However, **Query #2** I think gets `CompanyService#company` (with eager `city` resulting in `inner join City`)
- **Query #3** gets `CompanyService#service`
- **Query #4** is a mistery to me

I know this is not an answer, but it might help you understand what's going on in the background.

Comment: Thank you. What I am wondering is why the last three queries are even executed, when the first one is all Hibernate needs to do what I asked it to do. But maybe you are right that it isn't supported - but if that were the case, then it's strange that it correctly assembles query #1 to do exactly what I expected. Strange! :-)

Comment: Strange it is, but unfortunately I can't help more, and these are just my assumptions. Would like to see a comment from someone who is familiar with Hibernate's inner workings.

Answer (score 0):

I know that his topic is old, but this may help someone. I think that the reason for hibernate issuing additional queries during join fetch is that you also need to use join fetches for many to one - these are not loaded by default when you use jpql.